# Ajax DataTable Sorting

Tags: json, ajax, datatable

Is it possible to sorting based on data inside while loop? without using the sql order by.
But also after i select which column, it will sort desc or asc based on data inside not sort by database column and limit it only 10 every page

lookup.php

```
    $draw            = $_POST['draw'];
$row             = $_POST['start'];
$rowperpage      = $_POST['length']; // Rows display per page
$columnIndex     = $_POST['order'][0]['column']; // Column index
$columnName      = $_POST['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; // Column name
$columnSortOrder = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // asc or desc
$searchValue     = $_POST['search']['value']; // Search value

## Custom Field value
$searchByName    = $_POST['searchByName'];
$searchByGender  = $_POST['searchByGender'];
$sel = $con->query("SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.nrek=b.nrek GROUP BY a.name");
$records = $con->num_rows();
$totalRecords = $records;

## Total number of records with filtering
$sel = $con-query("SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.nrek=b.nrek AND 1 ".$searchQuery."GROUP BY a.name");
$records = $con->num_rwos();
$totalRecordwithFilter = $records;


               $empQuery = $con->query("SELECT * FROM a, b, c WHERE a.nrek=b.nrek AND a.kode=c.kode AND a.kode='3' GROUP BY a.nrek ORDER BY ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder." limit ".$row.",".$rowperpage");

               while ($row1 = $empquery->fetch_array()) 
               {            
                   $querybalance2       = $con->query("SELECT SUM(b.balance) as balance FROM a JOIN a ON a.nrek= b.nrek WHERE a.kode= '$row1[kode]' AND b.period='$_SESSION[lastperiod]'");

                   $querybalance2       = $con->query("SELECT SUM(b.balance) as balance FROM a JOIN a ON a.nrek= b.nrek WHERE a.kode= '$row1[kode]' AND b.period='$_SESSION[newperiod]'");

                   $balance2 = $querybalance2->fetch_array();
                   $balance1 = $querybalance1->fetch_array();

                  $data[] = array(
                    "arek"=>$row1[nrek],
                    "balance1"=>$balance1,
                    "balance2"=>$balance2
                   );
               }

    $response = array(
    "draw" => intval($draw),
    "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
    "aaData" => $data
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Ajax.js

```
var dataTable = $('#empTable').DataTable
({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'serverMethod': 'post',
    //'searching': false, // Remove default Search Control
    'ajax': 
    {
        'url':'lookup.php',
        'data': function(data)
        {

        }
    },
    'columns': 
    [
        { data: 'arek' },
        { data: 'balance1', className: 'text-center' },
        { data: 'balance2', className: 'text-center' },
    ]
});
```

html.php

```
            <table id="empTable" class="display dataTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nrek</th>
                            <th>Balance1</th>
                            <th>Balance2</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

I want to limit it so the data will load and display faster. If user click on the column, datatable will sort it based on data not column. I tried but "invalid json response", because there isn't "balance2" column in database.

Need help and thank you

Comment: you can write a better sql to solve it, all your sql in sql , so you dont need to loop separately, and also use pagination, which send offset, limit , start to server, which you can use to load limited data or by pagewise

Comment: Could you help me how to combine into one sql?

Comment: if you provide your table structure. you need to add balance sqls to main sql, use join or , sub query

Comment: and the problem you get because of balance2, is because balance2 is your custom columnname, soyou have to check before doing query, i think $columnName   is the variable, check if its == balance2 then change it to respective column,